# PATCH using wrong model ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have got the following problem

[image: screenshot]

My edit function saves the model object with the id 33 as the id 32, and i dont know why.
here's my controller function:

```
def update
    @user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
    @user.ranks[0].update(user_params)
    redirect_to dashboard_ranks_path
end

private
def user_params
    params.require(:rank).permit(:points, :rank_name, :id)
end
```

The same method works on another controller but on this one it suddenly doesnt work for some reason. for example I have got 3 posts, I edit the first one, it does not change the id and it will edit itself successfully. However if I chose the second one it choses the id of the third one, if i edit the 3rd one it somehow patches the first one. Did anybody had a bug like that before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have multiple servers running your application? Are you using a database/redis backed session store?
Particularly, the way you get the rank **through** the user association seems to be the problem. Ideally you would do something like

```
rank = @user.ranks.find_by_id params[:rank][:id]
rank.update(user_params) if rank
```

Not relevant to the issue, but I'd suggest changing the name of user_params, to rank_update_params or something that does represent what they are for.

**EDIT**

The two first questions are relevant to know if the user that owns the rank you are editing is the same you are accessing from the session.

Comment: Thanks :) I've just changed `@user.ranks.update(user_params)` to `@user.ranks.find_by_id(params[:id]).update(user_params)` and that fixed it, thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `find_by_id` unless you're not using Rails 4

Comment: I am running Rails 4, I just noticed

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because you're not using the rank `id` variable...

```
@user = User.find_by_id session[:user_id]
@user.ranks[0].update user_params #-> how do you know which rank is first?
redirect_to dashboard_ranks_path
```

You'll be better doing the following:

```
@user = User.find session[:user_id] #-> find uses id anyway, and even then "find_by :attribute" is the `Rails 4` way of doing it
@rank = @user.ranks.find params[:id]
@rank.update user_params
```

This will select the `rank` based on the pased `params[:id]` variable which you've passed through your route:

`/ranks/edit/33`